# which is the best way to implement the offset in collection view?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

I need to implement an offset in my first column. I got it, but when I do scroll into view, the last cell still moves to the bottom. This happens each I do a scroll.

My code is the next.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let identifier = "Cell"
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) as! cellFavoriteTransferCollectionViewCell
    cell.titleName.text = "hola"
    cell.hero.id = "Cell\(indexPath.row)"
    if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
        cell.frame = CGRect(x: cell.frame.origin.x, y: cell.frame.origin.y + 50, width: cell.frame.width, height: cell.frame.height)
    } else {
        cell.frame = CGRect(x: cell.frame.origin.x, y: cell.frame.origin.y, width: cell.frame.width, height: cell.frame.height)
    }

    return cell
}
```

What is my mistake and how must I change the vertical scroll size because the last cell appear to the half?

[image: picture of my issue]

Answer (score 1):

You need to customize your cell layout attributes.

Follow this tuts might help you solve your issue: https://www.raywenderlich.com/4829472-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest